# A property of the "outerplanar" vertices of a plane graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a finite and connected planar graph with a given fixed embedding in $\mathbb R^2$. Now suppose we remove all vertices that are incident to an edge belonging to the outer face of the embedding, and suppose we have a non-empty collection $V'$ of vertices left (i.e. the given embedding is not [outerplanar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph)).

> Then if $U \subseteq V'$ we can find a cycle of vertices in $V \setminus V'$ such that $U$ lies in the interior region of this cycle.

How to prove this "obvious" fact?

Comment: If $V \setminus V'$ contains vertices of degree 1, remove them. What is left is the boundary of the outer face, and thus is a cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "obvious" fact is false. Consider the following counterexample. Let $G$ be two copies of $K_4$ embedded into a plane joined by an edge lying in the outer face, as below.
[image]

Given this embedding of $G$ and your construction in the question, the set $V'$ is given by $V'=\{v_4,v_8\}$. However there is no cycle in $G$ such that $v_4$ and $v_8$ lie on the interior of that cycle.

---

Suppose you make the further assumption that $G$ is $2$-connected. Then you can prove a lemma that the vertices and edges that make up the outer face in a planar embedding of $G$ form a cycle. That cycle should contain any subset of $V'$.